# Prove martingale $X$ times indicator function of $X$ is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales

Let $X_t$ be a martingale with a filtration $\{F\}_t$. Prove that $X_t 1_{r(X_t)}$ is a martingale where $r(X_t)$ is some relation involving $X_t$, for example $ X_t \leq 0 $.

### My attempt

We know $\mathbb{E}[X_t 1_{A}] = \mathbb{E}[X_m 1_{A}]$ for $\forall A \in F_m $  and $t > m $. Note that $1_{r(X_t)}$ is $F_t$ measurable while $1_{A}$ is  $F_m$ measurable. Hence the indicator of their intersection is $F_m$ measurable.
Therefore $\mathbb{E}[X_t 1_{r(X_t)} 1_{A} ] = \mathbb{E}[X_t 1_{A \cap r(X_t)}] = \mathbb{E}[X_m 1_{A \cap r(X_m)}] = \mathbb{E}[X_m 1_{A} 1_{ r(X_m)}]$ 
I am not completely sure about the second equality of the proof where my indicator of ${X_t}$ becomes an indicator of $X_m$. Is this correct ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Uh, are you sure that what you are trying to prove is correct? Let $X_t$ be brownian motion and let the relation be the one you defined (indicator on greater than or equal to 0); at time 0, it is certainly 0, but the expectation of $X_t$ times that indicator is not 0.

Comment: @E-A correct me if I am wrong, but a standard brownian motion at $0$ has $X_0 = 0 $ almost surely, so it's expectation is also $0$?

Comment: Yeah it is; so for the X times the indicator function to be a martingale, it needs to have the same expectation, however, that is not the case here.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is meant by "some relation involving $X_t$?